# Liking and disliking among the Napoleonic Marshalls of the Empire

Tags: napoleonic-wars, napoleon

It is anecdotical but I want to know if the Marshalls of the Empire appointed by Napoleon got well along or if they could hardly tolerate each other.

I'm specially interested in **Lannes**, **Davout**, **Desaix**, **Masséna**, **Murat**, **Ney** and **Soult**.

I already know - please, correct me if I'm wrong - that **Murat** wasn't very much appreciated by **Davout**, **Lannes** or **Ney**. That **Ney** and **Soult** hated each other after Spain. That **Desaix** and **Davout** were friendly, and that **Masséna** refused to sentence **Ney** to death after the Hundred Days.

If all of the above is correct, is there anything else worth mentioning - relationship wise - among these seven Marshalls of the Empire?

Comment: Good question, wish I knew the answer. Possibly [this book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1347907.Napoleon_s_Marshals) could be helpful.

Comment: Well, Bernadotte disliked Davout so intensely he risked court martial and possible execution by refusing to *march to the guns* at Auerstadt. As far as I know Bernadotte was both the only Marshall with *Death to Tyrants* tattooed on his butt, and the only one to found a still extant royal dynasty.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why include Desaix considering he died in December 1800?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, Desaix was part of the Egyptian expedition, so, despite his early death at Marengo, he had the opportunity to meet most of these men. It's for a little project of mine, I included Desaix on it because your Desaix posts in this SE convinced me it was the only reasonable thing to do :)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens the tatoo is a myth, coming from the play *Le Camarade de lit* by Louis-Émile Vanderburch and Ferdinand Langlé. Bernadotte did, however, once write in a letter that "Being a republican both by principle and by conviction, I want to fight all royalists to my death. " See http://www.faktoider.nu/bernadotte_eng.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to base the following of an essay by Frans G Bengtsson, "Marskalkarna av Frankrike", found in *Sällskap för en eremit*. The essay in turn was written after he had read Gabriel d'Orgeval's *Le Maréchalat de France* and, particularly the part I will take my material from,  G.A. Macdonell's *Napoleon and his Marshals*. I'll be using the word "hate" a lot as a catch-all since it is hard to tell from a short account exactly how strong the dislike actually was. I'll also cover dislikes between all the Marshal's, for the benefit of anyone finding this question in the future. Onward to the actual answer:

The Marshals seems to have rather disliked each other as a general rule:

- Davout, Berthier and Bernadotte all hated each other.
- Ney and Soult hated each other.
- Soult and Masséna hated each other
- Masséna and Bessières hated each other.
- Macdonald and Gouvion Saint-Cyr hated each other.
- Augereau and Murat hated each other.
- Lannes hated Murat and Bessières, and they hated him in turn.

The following pairs appears to have been good friends:

- Davout and Oudinot
- Murat and Bessières
- Lannes and Augereau

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. The Soult - Masséna hate was totally unexpected to me, searching in Google after your answer I've found this book: [The Baton in the Knapsack: New Light on Napoleon and his Marshals](https://books.google.es/books?id=IDJwCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&lpg=PT62&dq=%22soult%22+%22mass%C3%A9na%22+hate+OR+dislike&source=bl&ots=xTLAgUHwDg&sig=X9ZFkfaPTD66-phuVBZMfwszSqY&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22soult%22%20%22mass%C3%A9na%22%20hate%20OR%20dislike&f=false). It confirms most of your answer and also adds some Lannes -Soult hate.